# hardhat beginner "Nothing to compile" error

Tags: hardhat, compilation, compiler

following hardhat beginner tutorial.
This is how I did it,
first run "`npx hardhat` " command and created basic sample project. After that run following command

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers
```

After that run `npx hardhat compile`

but "Nothing to compile" message return  can anyone help me pls..!

Comment: You have to `cd` into the folder that gets created by `npx hardhat`.

Comment: An easier way than using the CLI might be to fork my [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template). It's Hardhat-based and has lots of plugins pre-configured for you.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg actually I did that, thanks for your concern. But still  problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found the solution from [Github](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2142)

First I deleted the node_modules folder after that run  `npm install glob@7.2.0` and `npm install` solved the issue. The problem was hardhat installation do not find the contact folder. Thanks all for your concern...!

Answer (score 0):

The major issue is that you haven't created a ***contracts*** directory in your project. Then you can write sol files in it and run `npx hardhat compile`. This worked for me.